How to call a native sql function using queryDSL
I use QDSL and Java.
I have a feature to search for IDs via full-text search. It returns a List.
This is the native sql that I'm trying to call through
I want to add a condition: Expressions.numberTemplate(Long.class, "get_ids({0})", filter.getTextSearch()) But numberTemplate does not work with arrays
myentity.id.in('array here') 

